# Unexplainable int behavior in encoder/LED project

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c++, rgb-led, rotary-encoder

I am trying to use a rotary encoder to cycle through the brightest versions of R, G & B. And it works! Red goes to blue just fine. Then G happens. For some reason, the int for green goes completely haywire. And it does this the same way on two Arduinos.

So my question is this: why would two, identically assigned variables treat `++` completely differently? After hours (and hours and hours) of looking, I'm completely out of possible answers.

```cpp
#include <Encoder.h>
#include <FastLED.h>

/* Encoder */
Encoder myEnc(2, 3);
const int swPin = 4 ;
long oldPosition  = -999;

/* LEDs */
#define LED_PIN     7
#define NUM_LEDS    150
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

/* RGB Loop */
volatile int cycle = 1;
volatile int brightness = 0;
volatile int r = 127;
volatile int g = 0;
volatile int b = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(swPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  // Read from rotary encoder.
  long newPosition = myEnc.read();

  if (newPosition != oldPosition) {
    oldPosition = newPosition;
    Serial.println(newPosition); /* Sends elsewhere */
  }

  /* Will eventually move this inside the above if 
   * statement so the color shift is controlled by
   * a rotary encoder.  Down here for debugging. 
   */
  delay(50);
  updateColor( );
}

void updateColor(  ) {

  Serial.println(" "); // For readability. 

  if ( brightness >= 127 ) {
    brightness = 1;
    if ( cycle > 6 ) {
      cycle = 1;
    } else {
      cycle++;
    }
  } else {
    brightness++;
  }

  if ( cycle == 1) {
    b++;
  }
  else if ( cycle == 2) { /* rb --> b */
    r--;
  }
  else if ( cycle == 3) { /* b --> bg */
    g++;
  }
  else if ( cycle == 4) { /* bg --> g */
    b--;
  }
  else if ( cycle == 5) { /* g --> rg */
    r++;
  }
  else if ( cycle == 6) { /* g --> rg */
    g--;
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("==================== ");
  }

  /* Debugging */
  Serial.print("brightness:");
  Serial.print(brightness);
  Serial.print("   cycle:");
  Serial.print(cycle);
  Serial.print("   r:");
  Serial.print(r);
  Serial.print(" g:");
  Serial.print(g); // goes completely bonkers
  Serial.print(" b:");
  Serial.print(b);
  Serial.println(" ");


  for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i].setRGB( r, g, b );
  }

  FastLED.show();

}
```

spits out the following in the serial monitor :

```
brightness:1   cycle:1   r:127 g:0 b:1 

brightness:2   cycle:1   r:127 g:127 b:2 

brightness:3   cycle:1   r:127 g:32639 b:3 

brightness:4   cycle:1   r:127 g:32639 b:4 

brightness:5   cycle:1   r:127 g:32639 b:5 

brightness:6   cycle:1   r:127 g:32639 b:6
```

Red and blue are doing exactly what I want. Green is off on Mars.

Any/all help would be enormously appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 127 = 0x7F, 32639 = 0x7F7F.

Comment: I can't yet comment so therefore here.
Could you try casting the rgb printouts to uint8_t? It could be that it goes out of bounds or something? I don't see anything wrong with the code so maybe it could be that some pointer is changing the value of g?

Comment: I do not see a relation between the encoder and the r,g,b values. Or between the encoder and your rgb problem. BTW: rgb values are byte, not int

Comment: laffan, we don't see the problem. It could be a compiler or optimization bug (not likely, but it is possible) or a bug in a library that overwrites memory. You have to try a number of things. Start with an example, and slowly change that in the direction of your sketch. The setRGB is a inline function that has uint8_t as parameters. I think there is no need to make the variables volatile.

Comment: Thank you all!  

@Jot I think you're on to something. I'm not sure _what_ you're on to, but that at least explains the number. Looks like I need to learn some more about hexidecimals.  And good to know re: that variable volatility (I was grasping at straws.) 

Tarik Welling - I'm afraid this hobbiest hasn't gotten to pointers yet, but I'll take a look. 

DataFiddler - The new/old position thing is the rotary encoder part (see comments) which works, incredibly. Thanks for the byte tip.

Comment: couple of things to try ..... comment out the FastLed code ..... exchange the `b++` and the `g--`  in the `if` blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
```

you are defining an array of `NUM_LEDS` objects of the `CRGB` type.
Valid indices for this array range from `0` to `NUM_LEDS-1`.

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
  leds[i].setRGB( r, g, b );
}
```

you are accessing the array elements at indices `0` to `NUM_LEDS`. The
last iteration is an out-of-bounds access, which is causing memory
corruption. You should instead write

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @edgar-bonet - I don't think I ever would have figured that out.